# Deployed a Qt application with linuxdeployqt, application runs on a machine without qt but throws an error when run on a machine with Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

Deployed an application with linuxdeployqt on centos7

The application runs on machines which don't have qt.
On other machines which have qt it throws an error

```
/home/tmcp/user1/folder
```

contains mpu executable along with lib, plugin and translation created by linuxdeployqt

```
/home/tmcp/user1/folder/lib/libQt5Core.so.5:version 'Qt_5.12' not found(required by ./mpu)

/home/tmcp/user1/folder/lib/libQt5Charts.so.5:version 'Qt_5.12' not found(required by ./mpu)
```

How do i resolve this error
I want the application to run with or without the machine containing qt

The machines with qt has the version as same as the machine from which it was deployed.(version 5.12.10)

Comment: Compare `ldd` command's output on machine where it works vs where it doesn't. It might give a clue. Maybe add the difference to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is the old pain with XXdeployqt on Windows and Linux. Just get those libraries from the build machine and put them next to program executable (same folder with ./mpu).